# Making text appear in the middle of a button

Tags: html, css

When I use

```
<button id="kh_send_comment">
    <i class="material-icons">done</i> 
    Save
</button>
```

the position of the word `Save` is on the bottom of the button. I would like it to be in the middle of it. How can I do this without changing the font size?

https://jsfiddle.net/ba3vg9k8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
button i { vertical-align: middle }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bgr3a1oL/1/

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is the button wraps around the larger icon, which increases the button's height and leaves the text hugging the bottom.

You can give the `vertical-align` for the icon a set pixel value to get the text exactly where you want it.

```css
button i { vertical-align: -7px }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<button id="kh_send_comment"><i class="material-icons">done</i> Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to the `i` element.